# Can I run high-performance games under Wine using a modern board (eg Z170)

Tags: wine

When I bought and installed Windows XP I promised to myself it would be the last Windows OS I would ever use. Unfortunately, some games are coming out that do not run on Windows XP and do not run on Linux either. One example I am thinking of is [Dragon Age: Inquisition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragon_Age:_Inquisition) which I bought, but cannot play, because it does not run on XP. According to an [older WineHQ post](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=31519), DAI will not run on Wine, but recently Wine support for DX11 seems to have appeared, so maybe that has changed.

I am thinking about buying a new Linux system based on the i7 and the Z170 chipset and a high performance video card like a GTX 970.

Will I be able to run most any game under Wine (or CrossOver) using a board like this, or will I run into performance or compatibility problems?

Comment: There is info on this on the wine web site. It lists comparability quality for a wide range of software. Wine is not an emulator, so it should not cause performance problems, though there may be high performance libraries missing that will.

Comment: not an answer to your question, but you might want to consider the GTX-1060 or 1070 instead of the GTX-970.  The 1060 is supposed to be faster than a 980 but just over half the price.  I bought a 970 in January...I don't regret buying it but I wish that the 1060 had already been released.